# Android ImageAnalysis - Analyze every n frame

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camerax

#### Problem

I am using [`ImageAnalysis`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis) to run a predictive model on certain frames on an Android App. Due to resource constraints, I can't run inference on all frames, so I'd like [`analyze`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis.Analyzer#analyze(androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy)) every `n` frames.

#### Example

Lets say I have a camera streaming at 30 fps and I want to analyze just **3** frames of those **30**. Moreover, I need those 3 inference to **not be consecutive**, but rather stretched along the second, for example:

`---------*---------*---------*`

`-` Not analyzed frame
`*` Analyzed frame

#### Current Approach

In the analyze method what I am doing is:

```java
@Override
public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {
    if (image.getImageInfo().getTimestamp() % 10 == 0) {
        // Run predictive model
    }
    image.close();
}
```

*Code assuming 30 fps.*

#### Question

Does the code above achieves what I described earlier or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: I think your code achieves what you described if you're using [STRATEGY_BLOCK_PRODUCER](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis#STRATEGY_BLOCK_PRODUCER), since there won't be any dropped camera frames in case analysis takes too long.